# Zendesk API - Notifications to end users are always from the user that is logged in

Tags: zendesk, zendesk-api

I am developing a simple connector for a contact form to Zendesk trough the Zendesk API. I authenticate with a emailaddress and token for the API. Everything works and i get the tickets inside of Zendesk.

The only thing is that when i create the ticket trough the API. The notification to the end-user is always from the user i was logged in to in the API credentials (email/token).

Is there a workaround for this? If i e-mail directly to: support@XXXX.zendesk.com, i get the e-mail from the organization name without a user name.

[image: Differences]

I use this API CAll now:

[image: Postman]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may not be a workaround when it's sending out tickets, which is why I see some people use `admin@domain.zendesk.com` and my org uses `api-user@domain.zendesk.com`.

Depending on what notifications you want to go out you may be able to solve this by re-routing the ticket using triggers to automatically reassign the ticket to someone else when generated.

Comment: Better late then never :) We tried this solution but the API doesnt seem to listen to the emailaddress provided in the email/token headers. Do you send a field in the RAW data containing that specific emailaddress (admin@domain.zendesk.com)?

Comment: I’m not sure how to change it with the headers. I’m saying you could change your zendesk API credentials to use a separate user (newly created) admin@domain.zendesk.com instead of your real user name. The admin user being the only user that makes api calls. That is what we are doing in our implementation.

Comment: Ah i understand. It feels weird to buy a (light)agent only to do the API calls but i understand your strategy now. Thanks for the quick responses.